# Problem on group actions

Tags: group-theory

> Does there exists an action of $\mathbb{Q}$ on a finite set $S$ such that $\text{Stab}(s)\neq \mathbb{Q},s\in S$?

*My attempt*:

I have been referred to a lemma that states that, if $G$, any group, acts on a finite set $S$ then, $\text{Stab}(s)$ is a *finite indexed* subgroup of $G$. I think that, $\mathbb{Q}$ don't have any non-trivial subgroup that has finite index.

*Question*: 
Is this claim about non-existence of such subgroups except the $\mathbb{Q}$ itself true? If yes can you give any hint how to show the result?

If the claim is not correct, then please help me to prove or disprove the statement in quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the claim is accurate. $\;\Bbb Q\;$ is a divisible group, meaning that for any $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$ and any $\;x\in\Bbb Q\;$ there exists $\;y\in\Bbb Q\;$ s.t. $\;ny=x\;$ .

Prove the following (reasonably easy)

Claim1: A homomorphic image of a divisible group is divisible.

Claim2: a Finite group cannot be divisibre

From 1-2 above the claim you mention follows at once.

Comment: Thank you, can you any give any example of homomorphism from $\mathbb{Q}$ to another group?

Comment: Well, it must be an infinite group so that the homom. won't be trivial...for example, what about $\;\phi_r:\Bbb Q\to\Bbb Q\;,\;\;\phi_r(x):=rx,\,\,r\in\Bbb Q\;$ . BTW, can you point out what $\;r\;$ is?

Comment: You taken $r\in Q$, so $r$ is rational number ?

Comment: I think these claims implies - "$\mathbb{Q}$ doesn't have any finite *finite indexed* non-trivial subgroup" , I mean not thinking about $\mathbb{Z}$, please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: No. The claim is "The rationals don't any non-trivial finite index subgroup" . Of course, they also don't have non-trivial finite subgroups, but this claim is almost trivial as $\;Q\;$ is also a field of characteristic zero.